# JWPlayer playing Flash Full-Screen

Tags: javascript, html, flash, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer 7.5.2 and playing an M3U8 stream via Flash since apparently HTML5 won't support M3U8/HLS streams in the browser. I can get our M3U8 stream to play, but I can't get the video centered in the div or to go full-screen. The following link is an example of the problem (the link is dynamically generated):

http://stage.flcbranson.org/php/mlmMediaRebroadcastStreamRequest.php?site=flcb&locationID=1&eventName=Sunday%20Rebroadcast&mediaID=5467&collectionID=189&collectionName=Willing%20And%20Obedient&contentPart=Pt.%2011%20-%20What%20Is%20To%20Be%20Done%20For%20Them&authorName=Keith%20Moore&locationName=Faith%20Life%20Church%20Branson&collectionStarted=Sunday,%20August%2021,%202016&vodPathName=/vod/smil:Weekend_Sun_RB.smil/playlist.m3u8

The following is my code:[image]
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I tried everything I've read in the documentation and get the same issue. Do I need to use JWPlayer's API to resize it's player?  If so, does anyone have an example using Flash?

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: The fullscreen button in JW Player on your site works for me on Firefox 48. What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Over the weekend, I discovered JWPlayer had a CSS conflict with my embed tag. Once I separated the CSS, JWPlayer rendered properly.